# Android fragment replace only works in onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been searching/struggling with this for two days now and I really hope it's nothing silly. I am trying to replace a fragment. The two fragments are being swapped in the same container in the activity. The fragments **BOTH** load fine individually if I swap the code in the OnCreate(), but when I try to replace the fragment from a callback I get the error. It can't seem to resolve the container 'R.id.authparent'. However, in the onCreate() it resolves just fine.

Here are the deatails:
I have my activity. This is where the ViewModel calls back to onRegisterNewUser() gets called and the fragment should get replaced.

**Activiy Class**

```
public class AuthenticationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IAuthenticationActivity {
FragmentManager mgr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
    Fragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.authparent, loginFragment, Constants.LOGIN_FRAGMENT);
    trans.commit();
}

@Override
public void onRegisterNewUser() {
    Fragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
    FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.authparent, fragment);
    trans.addToBackStack(null);
    trans.commit();
}
}
```

**Login Fragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "LoginFragment";
private LoginViewModel viewModel;
@Bind(R.id.input_email)
EditText _emailText;
@Bind(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@Bind(R.id.btn_login)
Button _loginButton;
@Bind(R.id.link_signup)
TextView _signupLink;
@Bind(R.id.login_progress)
ProgressBar _progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(view);

    viewModel = new LoginViewModel(getContext());
    FragmentLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_login);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    return view;
}
}
```

**Register Fragment**

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment implements IRegisterFragment {
private OAuthToken oauthToken = null;
private static final String TAG = "RegisterFragment";
private RegisterViewModel viewModel;
@Bind(R.id.input_email)
EditText _emailText;
@Bind(R.id.input_username)
EditText _usernameText;
@Bind(R.id.input_password)
EditText _passwordText;
@Bind(R.id.input_verify_password)
EditText _verifyPasswordText;
@Bind(R.id.btn_register)
Button _registerButton;
@Bind(R.id.register_progress)
ProgressBar _progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(view);
    viewModel = new RegisterViewModel(getContext());
    FragmentRegisterBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_register);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    return view;
}
}
```

**Login ViewModel** This is partial to save space, the only thing I'm including is the callback back to the activity

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModelBase implements ILoginCallBack     {
...

public void onSignupLink(View view) {
    if (context instanceof IAuthenticationActivity) {
        ((IAuthenticationActivity) context).onRegisterNewUser();
    }
}
...
}
```

ViewModelBase is really simple
**ViewModelBase**

```
public class ViewModelBase extends BaseObservable {
protected final Context context;

protected Context getContext(){
    return context;
}

public ViewModelBase(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected boolean checkEmpty(CharSequence s) {
    if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Finally the views:
**activity_authentication**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/authparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_login**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.savij.splitr.viewmodels.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.ProgressBarVisibility}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="46dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splitr_logo_crop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="@string/app_title"-->
        <!--android:textSize="@dimen/font_title"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />-->

    <!-- Email Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="@{viewModel.Email}"
            android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.emailChanged}"
            android:error="@{viewModel.EmailError}"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Password Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.Password}"
            android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.passwordChanged}"
            android:error="@{viewModel.PasswordError}"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel.onClickLogin}"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="No account yet? Create one"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel.onSignupLink}"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/link_lost_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Forgot password?"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel.onForgotPassword}"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_register**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.savij.splitr.viewmodels.RegisterViewModel" />
</data>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/register_progress"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.ProgressBarVisibility}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="46dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splitr_logo_solo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <!-- Email Label -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.Email}"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.emailChanged}"
                    android:error="@{viewModel.EmailError}"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.Username}"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.usernameChanged}"
                    android:error="@{viewModel.UsernameError}"
                    android:hint="Username"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Password Label -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.Password}"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.passwordChanged}"
                    android:error="@{viewModel.PasswordError}"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_verify_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.VerifyPassword}"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel.verifyPasswordChanged}"
                    android:error="@{viewModel.VerifyPasswordError}"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Verify Password"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:onClick="@{viewModel.onClickRegister}"
                />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="Already have an account?"
                android:onClick="@{viewModel.onLoginLink}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</layout>
```

The error I get is:

```
02-29 17:23:24.340 8064-8064/com.savij.splitr E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
02-29 17:23:24.370 8064-8064/com.savij.splitr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.savij.splitr, PID: 8064
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006c (com.savij.splitr:id/authparent) for fragment RegisterFragment{a34c76c #1 id=0x7f0c006c}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

So weird that it resolves the first time, but in the callback it blows up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to this and it makes a lot of sense. I think it's really that this is new material for me so I didn't think to look at the other DataBinding methods on the utility.

In my LoginFragment class I had this incorrect line of code:

```
FragmentLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(),
R.layout.fragment_login);
```

In reality, I don't want to set the content view. A few lines above this I am inflating the view I need so I should have been working with that. The corrected line is simply:

```
FragmentLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
```

Why it blows up when trying to replace the next fragment is really a strange by-product, but I'm just happy I found the answer! Hope it helps someone else too!